# Solve the matrix equation $A^{2}-2A=\begin{bmatrix} 5 & -6 \\ -4 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, matrix-equations

$A^{2}-2A=\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -6 \\ 
-4 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}$

Can someone help me solve this? I've been trying to solve it for a while, but no matter what I try, the only information that I manage to get about A is that if $A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ 
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}$ then $c=\frac{2b}{3}$. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Write it as $A^2-A=B$ where $$B=\pmatrix{5&-6\\-4&2}.$$
Then $AB=BA=A^3-2A$. The matrices satisfying $AB=BA$ all have the form $A=rI+sB$,
so put this into the equation, etc.

Comment: @AnginaSeng You mean $A^2-\color{blue}{2}A=B\implies AB=BA=A^3-2A^\color{blue}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Denote by $I$ the identity matrix. Then, completing squares you can write
$$A^2 - 2A = A^2 -2IA + I^2 -I^2 = (A-I)^2 -I^2.$$
Hence, your equation is equivalent to
$$(A-I)^2 = X + I$$
since $I^2 = I$. Denote by $Y=X+I$ the new matrix (which is known). You want to find $B$ such that
$B^2=Y.$
Here, I recommend to diagonalize $Y$, i.e. find $U$ and diagonal $D$ such that
$$Y=UDU^{-1}.$$
Thus,
$$B= Y^{1/2} = UD^{1/2}U^{-1}.$$
See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#By_diagonalization) for more information.

Once you have found $B$, $A$ is given by
$$A=B+I.$$
Remember that you may have more than one square root of the matrix $Y$.

Comment: Won't there be more matrix roots in general? When you diagonalize, you are solving quadratic equation at each diagonal entry separately.

Answer (score 0):

$$A^{2}-2A+I=\begin{bmatrix} 5 & -6 \\ -4 & 2 \end{bmatrix}+I \\ 
(A-I)^2=\begin{bmatrix} 6 & -6 \\ -4 & 3 \end{bmatrix} $$

We know that, if$$\begin{align}M&=PDP^{-1} \\ M^n&=PD^nP^{-1}\end{align}$$

Let $B=A-I$ then, $$B=\sqrt{\begin{bmatrix} 6 & -6 \\ -4 & 3 \end{bmatrix}}$$

Diagonalise $B^2$ as, $$\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt{105}-3}{8} & \frac{-\sqrt{105}-3}{8} \\
1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right).\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{-\sqrt{105}+9}{2} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{\sqrt{105}+9}{2}
\end{matrix}\right).\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{4*\sqrt{105}}{105} & \frac{\sqrt{105}+35}{70} \\
\frac{-4*\sqrt{105}}{105} & \frac{-\sqrt{105}+35}{70}
\end{matrix}\right)$$

From this, $$B=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt{105}-3}{8} & \frac{-\sqrt{105}-3}{8} \\
1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right).\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{-\sqrt{105}+9}{2} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{\sqrt{105}+9}{2}
\end{matrix}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{4*\sqrt{105}}{105} & \frac{\sqrt{105}+35}{70} \\
\frac{-4*\sqrt{105}}{105} & \frac{-\sqrt{105}+35}{70}
\end{matrix}\right)$$

From this $$A=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt{105}-3}{8} & \frac{-\sqrt{105}-3}{8} \\
1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right).\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{-\sqrt{105}+9}{2} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{\sqrt{105}+9}{2}
\end{matrix}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{4*\sqrt{105}}{105} & \frac{\sqrt{105}+35}{70} \\
\frac{-4*\sqrt{105}}{105} & \frac{-\sqrt{105}+35}{70}
\end{matrix}\right)+\left(\begin{matrix} 1&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)$$

The required matrix is approximately
$$\tiny{\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\left(481173769149-31173769149*i\right)*\sqrt{105}+\left(20341081920215+1091081920215*i\right)}{3500000000000} & \frac{\left(-481173769149+31173769149*i\right)*\sqrt{105}+875000000000}{875000000000} \\
\frac{\left(-160391256383+10391256383*i\right)*\sqrt{105}}{437500000000} & \frac{\left(-481173769149+31173769149*i\right)*\sqrt{105}+\left(20341081920215+1091081920215*i\right)}{3500000000000}
\end{matrix}\right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Tr}{\mathrm{Tr}\,}$
Let $Y=A-I$, $X=B+I$, $B$ for the rhs matrix. Then $\Tr X = 9$, $\det X=-6$, and we need to solve
$$Y^2=X$$
for $Y$. Write $\alpha=\Tr Y$, $\beta = \det Y$. Then
$$Y^2-\alpha Y + \beta I=0$$
or
$$\alpha Y = \beta I + X$$
so that finding allowed values of $\alpha$, $\beta$ solves the problem.

Take the trace and determinant of both sides of $Y^2=X$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\alpha^2 - 2\beta &= \Tr X = 9 \\
\beta^2 &= \det X = -6
\end{align}$$
which means that
$$\begin{align}
\alpha A &= (\alpha+\beta +1)I + B \\
\alpha^2 & = 9 +2\beta \\
\beta^2 &= -6\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Note that there are four solutions.

Comment: where can I read more about this method? All I could look up is the diagonalisation method